# how to pass list of lists for vectorize python

Tags: python-3.x, vectorization

For vectorization of python code, I have seen an example of passing a list of numbers for which our function is to be executed. 
example :

```
def myfunc(a, b):
 "Return a-b if a>b, otherwise return a+b"
    if a > b:
        return a - b
    else:
        return a + b
vfunc = np.vectorize(myfunc)
vfunc([1, 2, 3, 4], 2)
```

But our argument in the function is list, how to do the vectorization.

example:

```
def myfunc(a, b):
#a is the list

    if a[0] > a[1]:
        return a[0] - a[1]
```

Answer (score 1):

Since a is list object. Try to use loop method to iterate each values in the list.

```
def myfunc(a, b):
   # loop depends on the length of the list
   for i in range(len(a)):
       if a[i] > b:
          return a[i] - b
       else:
          return a[i] + b
```